# position fixed so that it moves other elements but also absolute so that it sticks to the top

Tags: css

Hello how can I make a div that is a banner on the top of the page. This banner should push other content down (any content) so that the current html page is rendered under the banner. But it should also stick to the top of the window if user scrolls down.

How can I make this CSS?

I tried with

```
position: relative;
```

no luck please help

EDIT:

position fixed works. My problem is that the content of the page may vary a lot since **this is a chrome extension** for several web pages. So with position fixed, the content of the page is not necesarilly pushed down. With position relative the content gets pushed down but then it dosen't stick to the top like it does with fixed.

```
.myMenu{
    position: relative;
    width: 100% !important; 
    height: 100px !important;  
    background-color: #40E0D0 !important
    min-width: 990px !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    color: #757575;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

This is my very simple code, I'm playing around with the editor of Chrome but like I said without any luck

EDIT 2:

I need the banner to push all the web page's content down no matter what the content is. Here are some examples of how it dosen't work with one of the web pages:

**Original web page**:
[image]

**Inserted banner with position fixed**: (it sticks to the top as expected but content is not pushed down) Ohh and FYI I'm prepending the content to the html tag like this:

```
$("html").prepend(myMenu);
```

[image]

So as you can see the banner is hidding the web page's content.

**This one is with position relative**:

[image]

in this case it works better but still no luck, since the search is still hidden and the web page's logo. Also the menu fails to stick to the top when user scrolls down.

Like I said this is just an example, I need my banner to stick to the top regardless of the web page's content. Any thoughts? Remember **this is a chrome extension for several web pages**

again thank you

**EDIT 3:**

So thank you all I got it working almost as expected. My situation is with the elements inside the body tag that have a

```
position:fixed;
```

These elements come into conflict with my menu. Is there some way to "wrap" the whole body so that all fixed positioned elements inside it are only fixed relative to the body and not to the window?

thanks

Comment: try position:fixed;

Comment: I have tried all kinds of position no luck

Comment: you need to provide a little bit more so we can solve that for you. Any code that you've already built or something? jsfiddle would be good

Comment: you can do this by using some jquery/javascript, just calculate the height of banner and use margin-top :calculatedpx; for content div

Comment: thankyou all for the help, I made an edit so my situation is clearer

Comment: @FahadSohail I tried to give you as much info as possible, I hope it helps. Thankyou

Comment: can you put your code on plunkr and share the link here?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `position:fixed;` for banner and set `padding-top` of body to the height of your banner.

```css
/* here 84px is the height of banner */
body {padding-top: 84px; margin-top:0} 
.banner {position:fixed; margin-top:-84px; width:100%; background:white;}
.banner img {height:84px; }
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <img src="https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/all/themes/easa_foundation/logo.png">
</div>

<div>
  <p>  The work of the Agency centres on ensuring the highest levels of civil aviation safety, through certification of aviation products, approval of organisations to provide aviation services, development and implementation of a standardised European regulatory framework. We further engender a culture of safety through our work in the fields of accident investigation, Safety Analysis and our research programme.</p>

  <p>The Agency acts as the focal point for coordination of aviation accident investigation safety recommendations and is responsible for the follow-up of occurrences where aviation safety has been endangered, as well as the internal coordination of the corrective actions that need to be undertaken, including actions proposed in safety recommendations.</p>

  <p>The Agency also conducts studies and provides reports concerning the safety of European and world-wide aviation. Data on the aviation system and accidents, incidents and occurrences is collected, categorized and stored and forms the base for its studies.</p>

  <p>Furthermore, safety research projects needed to support the Agency's tasks are specified, commissioned and managed. Working with partners we aim to 
leverage safety knowledge gains through joint funding schemes.</p>

  <p style="height:1000px;">...</p>
  <p>end.</p>

</div>
```

Comment: whats your feedback?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: fixed` on your menu div.

Check this: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5gruzy7w/1/)

EDIT: You can even use jquery to find the height of the `banner` div and give the same height as the `margin top` of the `content` div.

Comment: Instead of using `position: fixed;` for the elements inside the `body`, you can use `position: absolute;`. You can achieve the desired effect by using `position: relative;` for the `body` tag.

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps

add invisible blank space, same height with your banner/menu

[HTML]

```
<div class="myMenu">
   a
</div>
<div class="blank_space"></div>

<div class="content">
<p>
content1<br>
content2<br>
content3<br>
content4<br>
content5<br>
content6<br>
content7<br>
content8<br>
content9<br>
content10<br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
content1<br>
content2<br>
content3<br>
content4<br>
content5<br>
content6<br>
content7<br>
content8<br>
content9<br>
content10<br>
</p>
</div>
```

[CSS]

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.myMenu{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100% !important; 
    height: 100px !important;  
    background-color: #40E0D0 !important;
    min-width: 990px !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    color: #757575;
    z-index: 10;
}

.blank_space {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hv9zrx8q/1/

Comment: @Alejandro for your edit 3, add body { position: relative } and place fixed element inside your body.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position: fixed;` for your menu and for your content that you want to stay under it, you can simply put an `margin-top` equal to your menu height.

Comment: @Alejandro can you make a fiddle? It would be really helpful if we could talk over **your** code!

Comment: @Alejandro Where do you use `position: fixed;` exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Both position fixed and absolute are out-of-flow and thus don't push other elements.

You want "position relative so that it moves other elements but also fixed so that it sticks to the top"

This exists. It's called [`position: sticky`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#sticky-pos).

It's a new thing so it won't work on old browsers.

Comment: sticky dosen't seem to work in my chrome. I need something that will work with most of my customers

Comment: @Alejandro Try it on Firefox. For other people, you need JavaScript

Comment: Can't get it to work with Javascript. Other elements inside the Web page with position fixed are my trouble. Please see edit 3